# Can i put many subfolder of git repo in other repo

Tags: git, version-control

I have the parent folder in repo of `git`.

But i have many subfolders inside that parent repo which i want to have separate repo.

Can i do that in `git`

Answer (score 0):

Add your subfolders in the .gitignore of your parent git repo, so they will be ignored.

And do a `git init` to create a new git repository in each subfolder where you need a separate one.

Answer (score 0):

Better choice would be to use submodules:

You'd use one repo in your parent folder, modules in the subfolders reside in own repos that you pull in to your master repo.

Have a read about submodules in the Git Book: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules